# TFS Build Server gives service unavailable (503) message

Tags: tfs, build, permissions, tfs-2015

I recently installed TFS 2015 on a new machine. I want to configure the same machine as our build server but i have massive trouble doing this. I neither can configure the new vNext-system nor can i configure an "old-style" xaml build server. As the build account i want to use the NT AUTHORITY\Network Service. For the xaml configuration i set "Execute service as" to NT AUTHORITY\Network Service and use the same account for the connection to the team foundation server.

But when i add a new controller and want to browse to custom assemblies, i get a "service unavailable" error. So i decided to test without the custom assemblies, added an build agent and created a new build-definition for a simple test project. I added a build to the queue and wait. Nothing happenend (in the build window) until after about 50 seconds an error was shown in the build window: Service Unavailable (Typ VssServiceResponseException).

Same for the new vNext builds. I downloaded the agent.zip from the web-frontend, opened the powershell and started configuring the build-agent. After waiting some minutes, the configuration aborted with.... service unavailable.

So i decided to test something different : instead of using the FQHN, i used localhost and - tataaa - it starts the agent, which is also shown green in the web-frontends agent-tab. So i created a new vNext-Build-Definition and added it to the queue, but it does not start, but shows the message : "waiting for console output from an agent".

So i decided to test it on a different pc : i downloaded the agent to my laptop and installed it, configuring the agent with it's FQHN. Without any problems the agent was started and i was able to start and run a build.

So the question is : Why am i'm not able to configure the build service on the tfs. I guess it has something to do with permissions, but i don't now, what permissions the network service account should have. I also tried it with a local account, but with the same result.

Any hints are very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

BTW: I can ping the FQHN from the command-line.

This is the output, after trying to add a vNext-agent via the powershell.
[image]

**UPDATE:**
I used the the servers IP-address instead of its name and it suddenly worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take XAML build for example, to configure a Team Foundation Build Service, you must be a member of both the Windows **Administrators** security group on the server on which you are configuring Team Foundation Build Service and the Project Collection Administrators group on TFS.

According to the second paragraph, you can configure build controller and add build agent. Before queuing a build, you need to make sure the build controller and agent are in Ready status, sometimes relevant services are not yet fully available when you newly configure them or restart them.

Also, you may try to remove build service feature, and reconfigure it, to see whether you can solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I am a member of the administrators group in both windows and tfs. I created a controller and an agent an both are shown as "ready", but i have still no luck. I added a local "tfsbuild" account, gave him adminstrator rights and added it to several administrator and build-controller groups in tfs, but i alway get this http 503 error. I now think it's easier to separate the build-controller from the application-tier, since several test installations on other pc's worked fine, so it must be a misconfiguration of the server...

Comment: Installing build service on a separate machine works, but installing on TFS AT machine doesn't work..doesn't make sense. Have you tried to remove build service feature, and reconfigure it? In addition, check event log on TFS AT machine to see whether there is something useful.

Comment: I tried to unregister/register the build service over and over again, with different users and urls. Since it's tfs 2015 the feature is integrated with tfs itself and not a separate installation. I checked the event log, but nothing seems suspicious. I found a httpevent 'http://+:9191/Build/v5.0/Services/"' namespace reservation successful and that the build service has been started. I agree with you : it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. What do you mean by "Reset the IIS"? I restarted the whole server several times, which should be kind of a "reset" of all components. The OS is Windows Server 2012 R2, and i managed to make another windows server 2012 R2 machine into a build server, as well as windows 7 machines.

Comment: Did you try to add http://+:9191/Build/v5.0/Services/ to trust sites? Did you try to use the IP address of server instead of FQHN?

Comment: I added the site via the internetoptions, with no avail. The firewall has the rules for port 9191 and i tried the ip-adress. But nothing of this worked, the 503 error is still occuring.

Comment: I don't know why, but i tried the ip address again and it suddenly worked. Maybe there was a typo the last time... anyway, thanks for your help!